# Javascript - How do I replace all spaces that are only between a number and letter

Tags: javascript, regex

```
"5 Teams 7 Players" ====> 5Teams 7Players
"7 Individuals 8 Teams 8 Categories" ====> 7Individuals 8Teams 8Categories
```

Comment: Where's your code so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Why doesn't `5 Teams 7 Players` reduce to `5Teams7Players` ? What have you tried? What problems are you running into when you try?

Comment: Your examples do no reflect your title; your example still has spaces between numbers and letters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `(\d+)(\s+)(\w+)`

[**Demo regex**](https://regex101.com/r/kZDbMl/2)

```js
var a="5 Teams 7 Players";
var b="7 Individuals 8 Teams 8 Categories";

console.log(a.replace(/(\d+)(\s+)(\w+)/g,'$1$3'))
console.log(b.replace(/(\d+)(\s+)(\w+)/g,'$1$3'))
```

Comment: I'd prefer `a.replace(/(\d) ([a-z])/ig, "$1$2")`. It's unclear whether OP wanted to match more than one space, let alone other kinds of whitespace. Also, there's no reason to match multiple digits or multiple letters, and I think `[a-z]` is a better definition of "letter" than `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

Both prasad's and smarx's patterns can be further simplied.  Just look for a digit followed by a space and leave out the space on replacement.

```js
var a="5 Teams 7 Players";
var b="7 Individuals 8 Teams 8 Categories";

console.log(a.replace(/(\d) /g,'$1'))
console.log(b.replace(/(\d) /g,'$1'))
```

Output (in case you don't want to click Run):

```
5Teams 7Players
7Individuals 8Teams 8Categories
```